# PFQuery not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, parse-platform, null

I have some code that is supposed to search through all of the `MapPoints` in my `parse` backend, retrieve the MapPoint that matches the id, and assign that MapPoint's `title` value to a string, so I can use that string as the value for the push query key.

```
NSLog(@"****staticobject****");
NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", staticObjectId]);

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapPoints"];
[query whereKey:@"marker_id" equalTo:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[staticObjectId intValue]]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"performed query");
    PFObject *object = [objects firstObject];
    newtitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[object valueForKey:@"title"]];
    NSLog(@"***newtitle****");
    NSLog(newtitle);
}];
```

When I try to use `PFPush` - I get a message that says that `newtitle` is `(null)` - meaning the above query never gets entered.

`[query whereKey:@"marker_id" equalTo:[[NSNumber alloc] ...]]];` must not be finding anything.

This is the console output for the first log:

`2016-08-12 12:34:41.355 sneek[1098:386496] ****staticobject****
2016-08-12 12:34:41.356 sneek[1098:386496] 15768840`

It should find that id in the database, I have verified that it is there.

Comment: why don't you log the error message? Log the error that's returned from the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock and post what you see

Comment: there isnt an error - i had a if block that checked for it, it never makes it into the query.

Comment: I see, then take out this line and see what the PFQuery does, you have to lock this down. Remove this line, then see if the query runs: [query whereKey:@"marker_id" equalTo:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[staticObjectId intValue]]];

Comment: ok one sec doing it now

Comment: I get `Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15571e9f0> { URL: http://www.eamondev.com/sneekback/respond.php } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 12 Aug 2016 17:44:03 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.10.1";`

Comment: i dont think the query ran

Comment: weird, I've never seen an alamofire error return like that with Parse, not even with using a stand alone server. Not sure what your set up is. but AlamoFire response like that is indicative of "AFNetworking" library return error.

Comment: yah i know what its from...it skipped the query and went to my backend without neccessary stuff

Comment: it is doing the same thing with ur suggestion its totally skipping query cause i can see any of the log messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120826/discussion-between-ewizard-and-loxx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the query to a different area that made more sense, and I think the fact that it wasn't in an `AFNetworking` block may have been what fixed it.